# CSS: Implementing CSS Sprites with input button image

Tags: input, css-sprites

This button is before CSS Sprites

```
<input type="image" src="/images/search-button.png" value="" id="search-button">
```

I'm trying to implement CSS Sprites with one of my search form and the problem is that if I use

```
<input id="search-button" class="sprites1" type="submit" value="">
```

it will look something like this.

[image]

As you can see the image on the right doesn't look right, but it is click-able.

Then I tried with

```
<span id="search-button" class="sprites1"></span>
```

[image]

Then it looks right! But!! I can't click on it.

So here is my CSS sprites code.

What I have to implement to get it look the one I want and I can click on it?

```
 .sprites1 {
        background: url('result.png');
    }
#search-button {background-position: -0px -462px; 

                width:16px; height:16px; float:right; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the default css that the browser uses on  elements. You should try resetting that css. I often use the following snippet:

```
/*  reset css of buttons */
.cssresetbutton {
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    background: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    color: blue;
    padding: 0px; }

.cssresetbutton:active {
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    background: inherit;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none; }
```

try adding the *cssresetbutton* class to your input element and see if it works.

**EDIT:**
You can also try not using a input[type=submit] element. For example:

```
<span id="search-button" class="sprites1" onClick="document.getElementById('formid').submit()"></span>
```

It will submit the form#formid element when clicked.

Comment: The image now disappear after I insert the class together with `sprites1` class

Comment: are you inserting it BEFORE the sprites1 class? like class="cssresetbutton sprites1". It makes a difference.

Comment: So it should be before or after?

Comment: before, like this class="cssresetbutton sprites1". let me know if it works.

Comment: Here is what I insert `<input id="search-button" class="cssresetbutton sprites1" type="image" value="">`

Comment: Hmm... can you explain to me why the "background-position: -0px -462px;"? Why 462px? Can you try removing it (keeping the cssresetbutton class)? See if it changes anything?

Comment: Because that is how the image of my sprites positioned and the position of it is -0px -462px

Comment: I guess I'm going to stick with this http://applesiam.com/ if you can see on the right search form. On Firefox it looks perfect, but not on chrome :/

Comment: Try not using a input element. For example: <span id="search-button" class="sprites1" onClick="this.form.submit()"></span>. When you click it, it should work just as a input[type=submit] element, trying to submit the related form. See if that works.

Comment: you mean that the cursor doesn't appear as that clicking hand (or something)? that's simple: add 'cursor: pointer' to the #search-button css. Or, inline: <span id="search-button" class="sprites1" onClick="this.form.submit()" style="cursor: pointer"></span>

Comment: No, is not even allow to click to submit the form :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10765/discussion-between-frd-and-ali)